# Gstreamer how to switch from video / x-h264 to video / x-raw

Tags: pipeline, gstreamer-1.0

I have the following gstreamer pipeline that works fine:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc user-id="user" user-pw="pass" location="rtsp://...:554/user=a...._channel=1_stream=0.sdp?real_stream" name=src src. ! rtph264depay ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! splitmuxsink location=/media/device/video/file_test_%02d.mp4 max-files=5 max-size-time=10000000000
```

I need to go from video / x-h264 to video / x-raw from the h264parse or from application / x-rtp to video / x-raw to include a textoverlay element.

If I use a decoder (decodebin, avdec_h264) the CPU consumption increases too much and the processing becomes very slow.

Pipeline with decoder:

1.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc user-id="admin" user-pw="syrus" latency=100 location="rtsp://...:554/user=a...._channel=1_stream=0.sdp?real_stream" name=src src. ! rtph264depay ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! avdec_h264 output-corrupt=false skip-frame=5 ! x264enc key-int-max=0 ! splitmuxsink location=/media/device/video/file_test_%02d.mp4 max-files=5 max-size-time=10000000000
```

2. 

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc user-id="admin" user-pw="syrus" location="rtsp://...:554/user=a...._channel=1_stream=0.sdp?real_stream" name=src src. ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc key-int-max=1 ! splitmuxsink location=/media/device/video/file_test_%02d.mp4 max-files=5 max-size-time=10000000000
```

Is there any way to do it without a decoder?
or is there any way to improve the performance with a decoder?